# Изменить значение в state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
let store ={

    _state: {
         login: "11",
         aut: ""
    },
    

    getState(){
        return this._state;
    },

    

    test (){
        return this.getState().login;
    }
    
    
}
```

Пытаюсь занести изменения в `_state.login`. Получилось прочитать значение при помощи `this.getState().login;` . Не понимаю как можно изменить значение login?

Answer (score 0):

```
let store = {
    // ...
    
    setState(newState) {
        this._state = Object.assign({}, this._state, newState);
    },

    test() {
        console.warn(this._state.login);
        this.setState({login: "22"});
        console.warn(this._state.login);
    }
}
```

Если Вы имели в виду именно `state` у `ReactJS`, то вот [state-and-lifecycle](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)